# using django-pipeline locally

Tags: django, django-pipeline

How can I view files inside STATIC_ROOT folder when I run local server (./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000)? I set up django-pipeline and collectstatic works as expected by putting minified file into directory designated by STATIC_ROOT. However, running the server and accessing minified file (in my case its http://localhost:8000/static/filterpages/js/vendor.js) gives me 404 page not found.

My directory tree

```
django_project/
├── filter
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── filterpages
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── filterpages
│   │       ├── js
│   │       └── vendor
│   │           ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │           └── jquery-2.2.2.min.js
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── filterpages
│   │       ├── index.html
│   ├── templatetags
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
└── staticfiles
    ├── admin
    └── filterpages
        ├── js
        │   ├── vendor.6238a90960e0.js
        │   └── vendor.js
        └── vendor
            ├── bootstrap.min.c5b5b2fa19bd.js
            ├── bootstrap.min.js
            ├── jquery-2.2.2.min.1d35678c5edb.js
            └── jquery-2.2.2.min.js
```

My settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'

STATICFILES_DIRS = []

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.CachedFileFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)

PIPELINE = {
    'PIPELINE_ENABLED': True,
    'JAVASCRIPT': {
        'vendor': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'filterpages/vendor/jquery.min.js',
                'filterpages/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'filterpages/js/vendor.js',
        }
    }
}

PIPELINE['JS_COMPRESSOR'] = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'
```

Comment: I half way solved the problem. If I remove STATIC_ROOT and set STATICFILES_DIRS to 'staticfiles' then I can access the static file in the browser. However, now collectstatic command won't work as it requires STATIC_ROOT to be set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my way. In url.py (root url, place at same directory with settings.py file).

```
   from django.conf.urls.static import static
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And restart server and try again to access js file